# How to save my account from ban from asking new questions?

Tags: discussion, support

Comment [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37777598#37777598) shows, even deleted questions also matters while banning the user from asking new questions.

I already got **5** **closed/on-hold** tag on my questions(includes deleted questions also), I am thinking next **3** more to make me **ban** from asking new questions.

How to save my account from ban from asking new questions?

Looks like **banning** thing is very soon that is confirm, **3** is not a big number here. so any suggestions where can i post my questions related to movies other than stack-exchange.

Comment: I have already told you. I linked you to the [MSE master FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) about how to fix this. If you *honestly* want to fix it, you need to follow that guidance. Moderators have no control over the question ban.

Comment: @Catija if moderators remove the onhold/closed tag it may have chances from unban.

Comment: If moderators remove the closed tag just to help you get around a ban, they're not doing their jobs as moderators and the other thousands of users on this site will lose faith in them. You are asking them to subvert their power for your benefit and that sort of behavior is not acceptable anywhere on this network.

Comment: Seriously... I don't understand your attitude. You have been given all the help we can offer. **Read** the FAQ. Help yourself. Do the work. Stop blaming everyone else for your poor-quality questions.

Comment: @Catija I am blaming myself for posting low quality questions.

Comment: Reopening closed questions does not remove the downvotes. The downvotes are the main driver behind the question ban. So even if the moderators did what you asked, it likely would not help. You can edit closed questions to make them better, and they will _automatically_ be flagged for users to review and possibly have them reopened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How to save my account from ban from asking new questions?

Firstly, if what I suspect is happening it's not a ban, more that you will be [**rate limited**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) to asking only a set number of questions per day/week.

So you'd better make each question as good as it can possibly be. So....

## Ask better questions!

Honestly it's that simple...*and that hard*. A good question can be really tricky to put together so you have to craft it carefully **before posting**.

Downvotes are received because the question is *"unclear, lacks research or is not useful"*. It says so right on the tooltip if you hover over the down arrow.

So what can you do?

Take some time...don't just dash off a quick question (or seven)...and

- **Make sure it's clear what you are actually asking**. If you don't understand a particular phrase or expression, try googling that. It might be, if it's a language thing then English Language Learners or English Language Usage on Stack Exchange might be a better fit.
- **You MUST do some research first.** Rewatch the movie again...Check Wikipedia, IMDB, Google, Quora  etc. for answers BEFORE asking here.
- **Is what you are asking important** to your deeper understanding of the film? General trivia questions aren't encouraged.

---

On researching I will paraphrase (shamelessly steal), this answer from [MetaStackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users#182380)

### How much research effort is expected of Movies & TV users?

> A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. In fact, asking a question on Movies & TV is the absolute last thing you ever want to do. You want to avoid it at all costs. You want to think of it as a horrible shame that will forever haunt you and pass down from you to your descendants. You want very much to find your answer some other way.
>
> You want to
>
> - Search. Like mad. Not just for 10 minutes...hours, days even. Use Google like it's your best friend. Change words around, (yes, result change based on wording).
> - Wikipedia is your 2nd best friend.
> - IMDB is a close pal too.
> - Find books.
>
> Anything to avoid adding another question to Movies & TV.
>
> You never want to hit that "ask question" button and absolutely never do you want to click the "post your question" button.
>
> After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking. Because so help me, if your question gets an answer within 30 seconds that has 10 upvotes within 3 minutes, **you did not do enough research.**

Comment: Now on wards I will post on quora then. thank you for suggesting me **new site**

Comment: I didn't suggest posting elsewhere...just looking elsewehere *before* posting here.

Comment: @DhanrajKumar Quora is a waste site

Comment: yes, use Quora for research if you can get passed the in your face registration which blocks you from scrolling or reading what's on the screen

Comment: I've downvoted this answer for the second half. Stack Overflow is **very different** from Movies & TV. They get 8000 (*eight thousand!*) questions every day, many of which are crap - which would explain why they're so keen to stem the flow. Most of their top users have hardly ever asked a single question. Many other sites value every single new on-topic question, and their top users lead by example and post many good questions themselves. While research is valued, that post you've quoted is way too hyperbolic to be appropriate for M&TV.

Answer (score 7):

They're almost all "zero research" questions.

In essence...

> I just watched this movie & I don't understand this bit.
>   Please explain.

People tire of this type of question very quickly - & when they are seeing half a dozen a day, then they become even more likely to down-vote them.

It's human nature.

As already eloquently explained by Paulie_D... improve the quality of your questions, do some research.
If you can Google the answer in two minutes, then do so.
If it's still not clear after you researched, **then** ask a question about it.